# Convert One time to another time zone not work in IE

Tags: javascript

I am facing some issue with 
Converting One time to another time zone it not worked on IE and Safari.

```
var myDate = new Date('20/02/2014 21:46:36 GMT+07:00');
alert(myDate);
var localtime = myDate.getTime();
var localoffset = myDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
var utc = localtime + localoffset;
var targettime = utc + (3600000 * offset);
var c_time = new Date(targettime);
return c_time;
```

Please help

Comment: Please could you format your question properly with some textual description and a question. Code-only questions are not good in our community.

Comment: I do not see any issue with the code:

var result = "";
var myDate = new Date('20/02/2014 21:46:36 GMT+07:00');
result += myDate +"\n";
var localtime = myDate.getTime();
var localoffset = myDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
var utc = localtime + localoffset;
var offset = 3;
var targettime = utc + (3600000 * offset);
var c_time = new Date(targettime);
result += c_time + "\n"; 
return result;

Comment: Try try but dont cry...!

Comment: It code worked properly in chrome, Firefox but not work on IE